# Can iphone built in mic listen to the sound over 22khz?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone, avaudiorecorder

I tried Can iphone built in mic listen to the sound over 22khz? What is the maximum frequency can be listed by iphone mic? And how far is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.faberacoustical.com/2009/iphone/iphone-microphone-frequency-response-comparison/

Looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum sample rate is 48KHz so the maximum theoretical signal frequency that can be captured is 24KHz by the Nyquist-Shannon theorem (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist–Shannon_sampling_theorem). I doubt the built in microphone is any good near that frequency, though (and Ryan's link supports that with frequency-response measurements).

Comment: -1 : The max non-aliased frequency that can be captured is **below** Fs/2, even if you have a non-realizable perfect filter and sample for an infinite amount of time.  With a finite sampling time and a realizable filter, it will be some percentage below Fs/2.  You can also capture frequencies above Fs/2 (subsampling) if you have another means of dealing with aliasing ambiguity, which doesn't apply in this case.